# Ruby inside html-erb files issue

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am putting this inside my erb file

```
<% @user_friend.each do |friends| -%>
  <%= content_tag :p, :class => "popin" do %>
    friends.email
  <% end %>
<% end -%>
```

and I am getting this error message :

```
compile error
/var/www/gitorious/app/views/campaigns/new.html.erb:25: syntax error, unexpected ')'
..._tag :p, :class =>"popin" do ).to_s); @output_buffer.concat ...
                              ^
/var/www/gitorious/app/views/campaigns/new.html.erb:28: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting ')'
;  end ...
```

Could someone explain how I can resolve this ?

Comment: Which version of rails are you using? Rails 2 doesn't want the <%= on content tag, while rails 3 does. If you're using rails 2, use <% content_tag .... do %>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`friends.email` is ruby code, you just need to do like below:

```
<% @user_friend.each do |friends| -%>
  <%= content_tag :p, friends.email，:class =>"popin" %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I knew about your answer. I am just trying to figure out how I can add some more complex ruby code inside a 'content_tag ...do ' trick ?

Comment: @user1611830 Off course you could, just wrap your ruby code inside `<%= ... %>`.

Comment: you still need to place friends.email <%= %>, all ruby code needs to be wrapped in the correct tags

Comment: ok, but that's what I did (see my post). Do you mean the content of the tag must be necessarily in this form "content_tag :p, my_content，:class =>"popin"" ?

Comment: but your line friends.email isn't wrapped